# Game Logic Programming in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, blender

I have some questions regarding Game Programming with Unity and I am very new to Game programming.

One of my questions: How do i program the "Game Logic" in Untiy? I am using Visual Studio with C#, Unity and Blender for Models. I assumed that i would have something like "main" method, where my complete Game starts and where i am loading animations/characters/maps etc. and also can include logic like when to show menus, cutscenes, intros, what would happen at what point of the game, etc.

But all i saw in tutorials is some .cs scripts which controls the animation of some GameObject. But how do i manage the complete Game logic (as stated above) with all that belongs to a full video game?

What am i missing?

And i assume that i will have something like a Database/Files, for saving save games, configurations, highscores, etc...how do i manage this?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [this tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial) it will help you get started.

Comment: Unity's model is slightly different than you're expecting - there isn't a single Main() method for you to implement. Instead you might implement the Awake() or Start() method in any MonoBehaviour class. Most of the resource management is done automatically - typically you simply put objects in a scene and then load that. I encourage you to look for a few tutorials (the [videos](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials) on the Unity site are a pretty decent intro - look for the scripting section).

Comment: Read the documentation please, you will get many useful information : [Creating gameplay](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingGameplay.html) + [Creating and using scripts](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingAndUsingScripts.html). Unity uses a [component based architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component-based_software_engineering)

Answer (score 5):

Every Unity script can be run only if attached to game object.
there is no main method because its already handled by Unity itself.

The approach you can have is like create a game object GameController which has script named `GameController.cs`

The `GameController.cs` has method such as Awake, Start, Update
you can create your game rule, game logic, etc in that class.

Other script such as `PlayerController.cs` that is attached on Player game object will access the GameController to put its score, and other things

In the `PlayerController.cs` script you will have

```
GameController gameController = GameObject.findGameObjectWithTag("GameController");

gameController.score++
```

This is just example of the simple work flow

Answer (score 0):

You can make Don't Destroy GameObject than Attach your "main" script.

Answer (score 0):

Unity prefers to use components that each control themselves using the reflected methods (often in conjunction with singletons) e.g.

```
private void Awake() {}
private void Start() {}
private void Update() {}
```

See MonoBehaviour for more https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html

This does not mean that you cannot use Unity for a more traditional top down approach. Where there is only 1 script attached to 1 GameObject with the above methods implemented on that main object. You can then use resources or asset bundles to load content dynamically

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html

Using the more traditional approach can make it more tough for designing and debugging, but should generally be more optimal in the long run.

You will also find that objects do need to be created but are still controlled by the main script in some form.

Answer (score 0):

Answering old question, but I came across a nice idea if you need place for global variables or methods for your game.

First create a C# script as a asset, but don't attach it to any GameObject. Create class like this in the script you just created

```cs
sing System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CommonWorld 
{
    public static AppState _instance = null;

    public CommonWorld() {
        // Your constructor here if needed one
    }

    // this makes this singleton
    public static CommonWorld Instance() {
        if (_instance == null) 
        {
            _instance = new CommonWorld();
        }
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

And then in your GameObject you can get your CommonWorld instance like this

```cs
    public void start() 
    {
        CommonWorld world = CommonWorld.Instance();       
    }
```

I find this an elegant way to share methods and variables between game objects.